# Is there an opensource web based media player which can play all video formats,podcasts ,ppt slideshow and word doc presentation?

Tags: javascript, flash, media-player

Is there any open source, Flash- or Javascript-based media player which can play all video formats (like  youtube) and pdf slide presentation (like scribd)? Is there any media player that can do both? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relatively easily find movie players (i.e. [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)). But they don't play arbitrary video formats, but usually flv, to which you will have to convert your movies with some tool like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html).

Pdf is a totally different story. Scribd behind the scenes uses pdf to jpeg (or some other image format) converter and then has just image viewer in flash. You can try to use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert your pdf to images and then use any of existing image viwer. Say [simpleviewer](http://www.simpleviewer.net/autoviewer/app/).

So far there is no one-size-fits-all player for those formats.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/). It supports a host of video/audio formats and has browser plugins. Not sure if it can open PDF files, though!

Comment: This one is not Flash based. It installs a separate plugin for the browser.

Comment: I know it is not flash based and I don't think there are flash based, open source media players that can play "all video formats". VLC is a nice, better alternative, for his particular requirement.